# how to reset the values in textbox from database and values get from database?

Tags: php, mysql

The textbox shown value from database.when i click clear button the values will be reset.but i can't do that.please help to me.how to reset the values from database in textbox.
code:

```
<a id="button1" href="http://www.cmatm.net/sample/sheet.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"  type="button" style="margin:0;padding:0;" name="button1id" class="btn btn-success" onclick="window.location.href='sheet.php'">Edit</a>
```

Clear

Comment: On click, do you want to clear value on textbox ? On database ? Both ?

Comment: i want to reset text box only

Answer (score 0):

*Hope I understand this right.*

**To clear a form you need to do this in this way:**

```
<button form="yourform" type="reset">reset</button>
```